# Utilisation de l'imparfait avec des questions

Tags: temps-grammatical, imparfait

J'ai une question concernant l'utilisation de l'imparfait avec des questions.

Donc, pourquoi **"Comment étaient tes vacances?"** est-il correct (et pourquoi n'utilise-t-on pas **"Comment ont été tes vacances?"**. Et en général, quand doit-on utiliser l'imparfait avec des questions?

Je veux dire que je comprends l'imparfait parce que ma langue maternelle est une langue romane, mais dans ce cas j'utiliserais le passé composé. (D'après ce que je sais, on doit utiliser l'imparfait quand on demande une description).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Pourquoi "Comment étaient tes vacances ?" est-il correct

Parce qu'on demande une description d'un événement passé qui a eu une durée  significative.

---

> 2. Et pourquoi n'utilise-t-on pas "Comment ont été tes vacances ?".

On peut le faire. Cette tournure existe aussi en français. Les vacances sont ici considérées comme un événement ponctuel.

Suivant le niveau de langue, il existe des façons plus idiomatiques de poser cette question :

> — Comment se sont déroulées tes vacances ?
>
> — Comment se sont passées tes vacances ?
>
> — Tes vacances, c'était comment ?
>
> — Alors, tes vacances ?

---

> 3. Et en général, quand doit-on utiliser l'imparfait avec des questions?

Difficile de donner des règles, mais l'utilisation de l'imparfait pour le passé composé ou l'inverse ne posent pas de problème de compréhension.

---

> 4. Je veux dire que je comprends l'imparfait parce que ma langue maternelle est une langue romane

Laquelle ? Le français se distingue de ses cousines par la disparition plus ou moins complète de certains temps comme le passé simple remplacé par le passé composé  mais je ne crois pas qu'il y ait de grandes différences dans l'utilisation de l'imparfait de l'indicatif entre les langues romanes, sauf peut-être le roumain.

Answer (score 3):

> Comment **se sont passées** tes vacances?

I'm pretty sure that this is one of many idiomatic ways to express the idea, using the *Passé Composé* form .

Answer (score 2):

L'imparfait s'utilise ici pour une action qui a une certaine durée dans le temps, alors que le passé composé s'utilise pour une action brève.

> Comment étaient tes vacances ?

est donc correct, mais la durée s'exprime parfois aussi dans le verbe **se passer** (qui s'utilise alors au passé composé). Je suis d'accord avec @LUNA pour dire que

> Comment tes vacances se sont-elles passées?

est plus idiomatique.